# How can I refactor this pattern to use less code?

Tags: php, refactoring

I have a function that I use to generate random hashes for unique keys, I set a number sequence (`generateRecordLocatorID(13,6,11);`)that I want to use and it will generate a key such as `873e874704-e3bf859b86-fe2c1dcad9`. Id like to keep this pattern, however Id like to refactor this function down a bit -- thoughts?

```
private function generateRecordLocatorID($n1,$n2,$n3) {
    $seed = str_split(md5(rand(0000000,9999999)));
    $rand = array_rand($seed, $n1);
    $convert = array_map(function($n) use ($seed){
        return $seed[$n];
    },$rand);

    $var1 = implode('',$convert);

    $seed = str_split(md5(rand(0000000,9999999)));
    $rand = array_rand($seed, $n2);
    $convert = array_map(function($n) use ($seed){
        return $seed[$n];
    },$rand);

    $var2 = implode('',$convert);

    $seed = str_split(md5(rand(0000000,9999999)));
    $rand = array_rand($seed, $n3);
    $convert = array_map(function($n) use ($seed){
        return $seed[$n];
    },$rand);

    $var3 = implode('',$convert);
    $NewAPI = $var1 . '-' . $var2 . '-' . $var3;
    return $NewAPI;
}
```

Comment: Is it for security purpose? If so, md5 is not the way to go. Have a look at Sodium, for a safe crypto generator; http://php.net/manual/en/book.sodium.php

Comment: @Ggg No it is not for security. More of a unique key lookup to specific database records.

Comment: You should write a function which contains the code you want to repeat and that use this function with different parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested this code, working fine:

```
private function generateRecordLocatorID($n1,$n2,$n3) {
    $nums = [$n1, $n2, $n3];
    $newNums = array_map(function($n) {
      return substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,31-$n),$n);
    }, $nums);

    return implode('-', $newNums);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like this (as per gorn suggestion?). NOT TESTED.

```
private function generateRecordLocatorID1($n1,$n2,$n3) {
    $var1 = generateOne($n1);
    $var1 = generateOne($n2);
    $var1 = generateOne($n3);

    $NewAPI = $var1 . '-' . $var2 . '-' . $var3;
    return $NewAPI;
}

private function generateOne($n){
    $seed = str_split(md5(rand(0000000,9999999)));
    $rand = array_rand($seed, $n2);
    $convert = array_map(function($n) use ($seed){
        return $seed[$n];
    },$rand);

    return implode('',$convert);
}
```

Comment: :) few mins faster

Answer (score 1):

Whenever there is a code repeated, you should refactor it into function like this:

```php
private function generateRecordLocatorID($n1,$n2,$n3) {
    $var1 = locatorIDPart($n1);
    $var2 = locatorIDPart($n2);
    $var3 = locatorIDPart($n3);

    $NewAPI = $var1 . '-' . $var2 . '-' . $var3;
    return $NewAPI;
}

private function locatorIDPart($nx) {
    $seed = str_split(md5(rand(0000000,9999999)));
    $rand = array_rand($seed, $nx);
    $convert = array_map(function($n) use ($seed){
        return $seed[$n];
    },$rand);

    $var = implode('',$convert);
    return $var;
}
```

If you want to continue with more refactoring, I woul put out some of the unnecessary assignements, like this

```php
private function generateRecordLocatorID($n1,$n2,$n3) {
    return locatorIDPart($n1). '-' . locatorIDPart($n2) .'-'. locatorIDPart($n3);
}

private function locatorIDPart($nx) {
    $rand = array_rand(str_split(md5(rand(0000000,9999999))), $nx);
    $convert = array_map(function($n) use ($seed){
        return $seed[$n];
    },$rand);

    return implode('',$convert);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and general answer (can be called with any number of parameters):

```php
function generateRecordLocatorID() {
    return implode('-', array_map(function($n) {
            return substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,31-$n),$n);
        }, func_get_args())
    );
};
```

Fun way to do it:

```php
function generateRecordLocatorID($n1,$n2,$n3) {
    $n = $n1+$n2+$n3+2;
    $str = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,31-$n),$n);
    $str[$n1] = '-';
    $str[$n1+$n2+1] = '-';
    return $str;
};
```